# How can I comment out PHP lines inside HTML file?

Tags: php, html, comments

In the middle my HTML code, I have a line of PHP. now, I want to make PHP line as a comment.
I tried to ues `<!--  -->` but it seems not work for PHP.

What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: One thing you must realize, is that PHP is being executed BEFORE the page is sent to browser. HTML comments are meant for browser, so they have no effect on PHP.

Comment: As explained below by Sarfraz allowing <!-- --> to comment out php would make the php code visible for the client if they look at the html "source" (CTRL-U), a serious security issue. This is one good reason to chose that php (server side) would ignore the html comment-out. Another good reason as explained my Mchl is that otherwise, since php is interpreted (server side) by php, this would force php to interpret the html, which it does not in the present state: it only looks for <?php and ?>

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Imagine you have the following code:

```
<body>
    <?php echo $this_variable_will_echo_a_div; ?>
</body>
```

If you want the div to be echoed but not displayed at the page, you'll **comment html**, PHP still gets executed:

```
<body>
    <!-- <?php echo $this_variable_will_echo_a_div; ?> -->
</body>
```

If you don't want the div to appear at the source as commented html, you'll have to **comment php**, nothing will appear between the body tags at your source:

```
<body>
    <?php /* echo $this_variable_will_echo_a_div; */ ?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 9):

All the commenting methods of PHP syntax works in the embedded code inside HTML.
Feel free to use anyone.

```
<?php //for one line comment ?>

<?php /* for multi-lines comment */ ?>
```

also you can use the HTML comment syntax just outside the php tags.

```
<!-- <?php blah blah ?> -->
```

Note that the PHP code will still be executed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [PHP Comments](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/comment.php) not HTML comments `<!-- -->`

Note that you should hide PHP code for security reasons when commenting out a chunk of HTML containing PHP code using `<!-- -->` otherwise your source code will be visible when page is viewed.

Comment: For the same reason, you cannot use // if your php code is single line.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
<?php
/*
    <?php
        php code.. blah blah
    ?>
*/
?>
```

Or

```
<?php
    // <?php echo 'hi'; ?>
?>
```

Or

```
<?php
    # <?php echo 'hello'; ?>
?>
```

Comment: Not really. The comment flag must be *inside* the PHP tags. Like `<?php // line of code ?>`. Otherwise they're interpreted as HTML characters.

Answer (score 2):

Comment out whatever code you wish with the usual HTML comment tags. Put a space between the p and h of php. For historical purposes, add an additional comment for any other code author who may do any editing in the future.
*Note: Recommended for temporary use only when the commented out code will eventually be deleted. (I used it while waiting for approval from a client.)

```
 <!--Nullified php call with spaces between the letters p and h within commented-out html code -->
 <!-- <div class="foo">
                <?p hp require($INC_DIR. "unneeded.php"); ?>
            </div>-->
```